# AVL Tree implementation in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, c++14

I'm looking for a general review of this AVL tree implementation:

```
#pragma once
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

namespace mds {
    template<
        typename T, 
        typename Func = std::less<T>
    >
    class avl_tree {

        struct Node {
            T     key;
            int   h;
            Node *left;
            Node *rigth;
        };

        Node       *nil;
        Node       *root;
        Func        cmp;
        std::size_t len;

        template<typename ChildA, typename ChildB>
        Node* rotate(Node* n, ChildA childA, ChildB childB) {
            auto new_root    = childA(n);
            childA(n)        = childB(new_root);
            childB(new_root) = n;
            n->h             = compute_h(n);
            new_root->h      = compute_h(new_root);

            return new_root;
        }

        void destroy_tree(Node *n) {
            if (n == nil) {
                return;
            }
            destroy_tree(n->left);
            destroy_tree(n->rigth);
            delete n;
        }

        template<typename ChildA, typename ChildB>
        Node* tri_node_rotate(Node* x, ChildA childA, ChildB childB) {
            auto c = childA(x);
            if (childA(c)->h < childB(c)->h) {
                childA(x) = rotate(c, childB, childA);
            }
            return rotate(x, childA, childB);
        }

        Node* restructure(Node *n) {
            if (n->left->h > n->rigth->h) {
                return tri_node_rotate(n, left, rigth);
            }
            return tri_node_rotate(n, rigth, left);
        }

        void maintain_invariant(Node *&n) {
            n->h = compute_h(n);
            if (un_balance(n)) {
                n = restructure(n);
            }
        }

        int compute_h(const Node* n) const {
            return 1 + std::max(n->left->h, n->rigth->h);
        }

        bool un_balance(const Node *x) const {
            return std::abs(x->left->h - x->rigth->h) > 1;
        }

        template<typename TT>
        void insert_recursive(Node*& n, TT& key) {
            if (n == nil) {
                n = new Node{
                    std::forward<TT>(key),0, nil, nil
                };
                ++len;
            }
            else if (cmp(key, n->key)) {
                insert_recursive(n->left, key);
            }
            else if (cmp(n->key, key)) {
                insert_recursive(n->rigth, key);
            }
            maintain_invariant(n);
        }

        void remove(Node *&n, const T& key) {
            if (n == nil) {
                return;
            }
            if (cmp(n->key, key)) {
                remove(n->rigth, key);
            }
            else if (cmp(key, n->key)) {
                remove(n->left, key);
            }
            else if (remove_node(n)) {
                --len;
                return;
            }
            maintain_invariant(n);
        }

        bool remove_node(Node *&n) {
            auto removed = n;
            if (n->left == nil) {
                n = n->rigth;
            }
            else if (n->rigth == nil) {
                n = n->left;
            }
            else {
                auto m = min(n->rigth);
                n->key = m->key;
                remove(n->rigth, m->key);
                return false;
            }
            delete removed;
            return true;
        }

        Node* min(Node *n) const {
            if (n->left == nil) {
                return n;
            }
            min(n->left);
        }

        static Node*& left(Node* n) {
            return n->left;
        }
        static Node*& rigth(Node* n) {
            return n->rigth;
        }

        template<typename Func>
        void in_order_recursive(Node* n, Func func) const {
            if (n == nil) {
                return;
            }
            in_order_recursive(n->left, func);
            func(n->key);
            in_order_recursive(n->rigth, func);
        }

    public:

        avl_tree(Func pcmp)
            : nil(new Node{ T(), -1, nullptr, nullptr }),
            root(nil),
            cmp(pcmp)
        { }

        avl_tree()
            : avl_tree(Func())
        { }

        ~avl_tree() {
            destroy_tree(root);
            delete nil;
        }

        void insert(const T& key) {
            insert_recursive(root, key);
        }
        void insert(T&& key) {
            insert_recursive(root, std::move(key));
        }
        template<typename... Args>
        void emplace(Args&&... args) {
            insert_recursive(root,
                T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }

        template <typename Func>
        void walk(Func func) const {
            in_order_recursive(root, func);
        }

        void remove(const T &key) {
            remove(root, key);
        }
        std::size_t size() const {
            return len;
        }

        bool contains(const T& key) const {
            auto n = root;
            while (n != nil) {
                if (cmp(n->key, key)) {
                    n = n->rigth;
                }
                else if (cmp(key, n->key)) {
                    n = n->left;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things that I noticed that may help you improve your code.

### Don't use `#pragma once`

Although it is supported by some compilers, code which is intended to be reused should avoid non-standard extensions.  For better portability, use a plain old include guard.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code uses `std::less<T>` but doesn't include the corresponding header.  The code should have

```
#include <functional>
```

### Avoid shadowing names

The typename Func in `in_order_recursive` and in `walk` shadows the `Func` that is part of the main template.  It would be better to use a unique name to alert the user that they are not the same function.

### Fix the spelling error

You should fix the spelling of "rigth" and make it "right".  No pun intended!

### Provide a destructor

Right now, this structure is guaranteed to leak memory because it has no destructor.

### Think of the user

A user of this structure has the ability, via `walk` to traverse the tree in order and apply a supplied function to each item.  It might be nice to add some capabilities other than that, such as providing a public method for getting the minimum and maximum values.  It would be nice to provide an iterator as well.

### Provide a constructor supporting `std::initializer_list`

Providing support for `std::initializer_list` is often quite easy and often very useful.  Here's one way it might be done here:

```
avl_tree(std::initializer_list<T> list, Func pcmp)
    : nil(new Node{ T(), -1, nullptr, nullptr }),
    root(nil),
    cmp(pcmp)
{ 
    for (auto item : list) {
        insert(item);
    }
}

avl_tree(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    : avl_tree(list, Func())
{ }
```

That allows us to declare and initialize a tree in a single statement:

```
mds::avl_tree<std::string> tree{"January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
    "October", "November","December"};
```